# counting weight-average of a sequence of doubles

Tags: c#, double

I have long sequence of double numbers (let's assume that not longer than 100 000).
Let's also assume that each number is not bigger than 200 000. If my algorithm below is suitable for such calculations? Will it be precise enough?

For example if I sum 100 000 times 200 000 and than devide to 100 000 I expect to have something between 199 999 and 200 001, but not 200 100 or something like that (though for these particular numbers it seems my class works perferctly, thanks to MarcinJuraszek for testing)

```
class Candle
{

    public Candle(double value)
    {
        ValueUpdated(value);
    }

    private double sum = 0;
    private double count = 0;

    public void ValueUpdated(double value)
    {
        sum += value;
        count++;
    }

    public double WeightAverage
    {
        get { return sum / count; }
    }

}
```

Comment: The precision of a double in C# is 15-16 decimal places. since you are only looking for precision in the 6th decimal place, I can't imagine that this would be an issue for you.

Comment: FYI This generally isn't normally called a "weighted average" but a "rolling" or "moving" average. As @DavidHope said, the precision you are looking for will be OK, but keep in mind if you for some reason are calculating the average of more than `2147483647` items it will fail.

Comment: I did some quick tests and using 500,000 test items, I was seeing errors at the 16th decimal place

Comment: For what it's worth - your code above does a straight (arithmetic) average, not a weighted average.

Comment: @NominSim - Why 2147483647? I ran his test at that number of entries and only had error in the 9th decimal place. I'd think you'd have to get 3 orders of magnitude higher to reach the 6th decimal place.

Comment: @NominSim right this is probably just "average". before that code I was using (Max-Min) / 2 which can be much different....

Comment: @DavidHope A unique property of adding the same number that many times results in a correct average. I was referring to the fact that the integer he uses to count will overflow at that point and that the new "count" will not be what he expects.

Comment: His count was also a double

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double-precision floating point numbers have 52 fractional bits, that is they have approximately log10(2 ^ 52) ~= 16 decimal places of precision. Since you only require 6 decimal places of precision, you should be perfectly fine.

Why not test it, though?

```
double sum = 0.0;
int count = 100000;
for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
    sum += 200000.0;
}
double average = sum / (double)count;
Console.WriteLine(average); // prints out exactly 200000
```

Comment: because testing VM-executed code doesn't prove anything. another guy can have another VM we should rely on specs :)

Comment: @javapowered What this code does is defined by the C# specification. C# defines double as System.Double which is an IEEE754 64-bit float (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.aspx). Therefore you can rely on always having the precision of this numeric type and this test will give the same results on any valid implementation of C# and the CLR.

Answer (score 0):

You definitely has a bug on your loop. Just tried:

```
var candle = new Candle(200000);

for (int i = 1; i < 100000; i++)
    candle.ValueUpdated(200000);

Console.WriteLine(candle.WeightAverage);
```

The result is predictable and correct: **200000**!

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/678hzkk9%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) double precision is set up to 15-16 digits, what is far more than you need.

Comment: well i didn't tried your loop at all. I just guessed that it can fail. if it can't - it's a good news. probably someone can suggest another better/faster way without "accumulating" a huge sum...

Answer (score 0):

As noted a `double` has a precision of 15-16 decimal places.  So as long as the **range** of your values (either the straight values or the value times the weight for a weighted average) is 15 digits or less you should be fine.